# Send JSX data as JSON from Express backend and then display it as component in React Frontend

Tags: json, reactjs, express, jsx

I am creating a simple react front-end with Express backend. Can I get express to send me JSX data as JSON so I can fetch it in react and display it as a component? Currently I am sending  JSON data and displaying it in react as a component and it works fine, How can I send JSX data as JSON?

Here is the code till now,
React front-end:-

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = { users: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users => this.setState({ users }))
      .catch(error => { });
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="App">
        <h1>Users</h1>
        {this.state.users.map(user => <div key={user.id}>
            {user.username}
          </div>)}
      </div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Express Backend:-

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  // Comment out this line:
  //res.send('respond with a resource');

  // And insert something like this instead:
  res.json([
    {
      id: 1,
      username: "samsepi0l"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      username: "D0loresH4ze"
    }
  ]);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Why on earth you would like to send JSX data via JSON?

Comment: What even *is* "JSX data"?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation seems correct but there is an error in the request.

Your React component should be requesting `http://localhost:3001/` or you should change your Express endpoint to `router.get('/users', ...`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to retrieve data from express you are making a call to `/users` but there is no code present in express to recieve or respond to this call.
You need to add an additional `router.get("/users", function(req, res, next) { }` to make this call work. I don't think there could be any reason to send JSX component (*I guess you meant components when you stated data*) via a request back to react.
Please describe the actual problem that you want to solve.